# How do I get a status report of all files currently being uploaded via a HTTP form on an Apache Server?

Tags: apache, http, file, upload, status

How do I get a status report of all files currently being uploaded via HTTP form based file upload on an Apache Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with Apache itself. The upload looks like nothing more than a POST as far as Apache cares. There are modules and other servers that do special processing to uploads so you may have some luck there. It would probably be easier to keep track of it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/), its uses Flash (in a nice way) to assist with managing multiple uploads.

There are events you can monitor for how many files of a set have been uploaded.